# Grafana - Adding large amount of SELECT fields to a dashboard

Tags: grafana

Is it possible to add a large amount of SELECT fields(in my example) to the dashboard?

Lets say I have 96 processors on an ESXi host I want to monitor metrics on, is there a less tedious way other than manually adding each field in the "Metrics" tab?

Answer (score 0):

Use single query with proper `GROUP BY` part, so this single query returns multiple time series, which will be visualized by Grafana.

Comment: I think you misunderstood or I explained poorly as no matter what I do in GROUP BY it isn't achieving what I need -- I have 100 field values I want to add to my SELECT, I just want to know if there's a way I can add them all without needing to click the + button and do it 1 by 1. 

The current query inspector is displaying the 1 field:
     `"q": "SELECT \"esxi-cpuload12\" FROM \"system\" WHERE (\"agent_host\" = 
    '10.255.255.51') AND time >= now() - 6h GROUP BY \"agent_host\"",`

But ideally I want the select to show a wilcard* to grab them all.